# IP addresses / ranges required for Azure Search to index Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cognitive-search

I have a Cosmos DB locked down to a vnet (and its subnets) and am looking to have this Cosmos DB be a data source for Azure Search.

When I attempt to configure it, it complains about being blocked by the firewall.

1. If I enabled "Accept connections from within public Azure datacenters" it still complains about being blocked by a firewall.
2. If I remove the "Accept connections from within public Azure datacenters
   " setting and grant access to the following IP 13.76.208.129 it works.

Is it only 13.76.208.129 that is actually required for integration or is there a larger range I need to add into the firewall?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in this [documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-iaas-to-azure-search-using-indexers?#managing-ip-address-fluctuations):

> If your search service has only one search unit (that is, one replica
> and one partition), the IP address will change during routine service
> restarts, invalidating an existing ACL with your search service's IP
> address.
>
> One way to avoid the subsequent connectivity error is to use more than
> one replica and one partition in Azure Search. Doing so increases the
> cost, but it also solves the IP address problem. In Azure Search, IP
> addresses don't change when you have more than one search unit.